# Google Sheets AppsScript function for dynamic url from cell value to Google Drive

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a Google Sheet called MAIN and in cell A10 I have a Dropdown and based upon the value of the drop down the value in Cell D10 changes to display a concatenated value hyperlink to that Google Drive Folder. I found on stack overflow a way to get a pop up that has a link to the URL since the Browser.msgBox doesn't seem to let me put a live URL in it. My request is to find a way to continue using the Browser.msgBox to allow a clickable link to open that google drive or to use what I found on Stack Overflow which does work, but it's not dynamic. So the value in D10 is concatenate("https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/",MAIN!A10). I would like the below to allow me to use a dynamic url like I have in cell D10. Thanks

```
function configExport(){
  showAnchor("Click here",'https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Tt5GRgsAIvL3uTEsCwXJMf7fC9g28G-X');
}

function showAnchor(name,url) {
  var html = '<html><body><a>Configs generated and exported to the Google Drive link below.</a><br><br><br><a href="'+url+'" target="blank" onclick="google.script.host.close()">'+name+'</a></body></html>';
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html)
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui,"7705 eNSE configs");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand `use a dynamic url like I have in cell D10`, I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to use the value of "D10" of "MAIN" sheet as `url` of `showAnchor(name,url)` using Google Apps Script.

In this case, how about the following modification? In this modification, the function `configExport` is modified.

#### Modified script:

```js
function configExport() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("MAIN");
  const url = sheet.getRange("D10").getValue();
  showAnchor("Click here", url);
}
```

- By this modification, when this function is run, a current value is retrieved from "D10" of "MAIN" sheet, and the retrieved value is used as `url` of `showAnchor(name,url)`.